# Issue with EditText doesn't get Focus in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I have a fragment which is called from a main activity, in the fragment I have an `EditText` that listens for a scanned barcode.

```
private void InputListener() {
    etInput.requestFocus();
    etInput.setOnEditorActionListener((v, actionId, event) -> {
        if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
            String scanned;
            scanned = etInput.getText().toString().replace("\n", "").trim();

            if (scanned.length() != 8) {
                globals.PlayFile(Globals.Sounds.Bell);
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "Not an 8 Digit Barcode!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                ColouredSnackbar.alert(snackbar).show();
            } else if (!scanned.substring(0, 2).equals("00") && !scanned.substring(0, 2).equals("01")) {
                globals.PlayFile(Globals.Sounds.Bell);
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "Please Check barcode!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                ColouredSnackbar.alert(snackbar).show();
            } else {
                //Barcode Good
                AddPoscode(scanned);
            }
            etInput.setText("");
            scanned = "";
            etInput.requestFocus();
        }

        return false;
    });
}
```

This works as it should and focus is regained on the edittext to await the next scan.

However, if I run this code from a fragment which has been called from another fragment instead of the main activity, then focus is not regained on the `EditText`.

Does anyone know why this is?

I am using

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'
```

The xml for both edittexts is the same

```
  <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etInput"
/>
```

My second fragment (called from another fragment) is called by this:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("PickListID", h.getPickListID());
                MySecondFrag = new  MySecondFrag();
                FragmentTransaction t = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                p.setArguments(b);
                t.replace(R.id.frame_container, p);
                Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                toolbar.setTitle("Frag2");
                t.addToBackStack(null);
                t.commit();
```

Update - I don't think the issue is because it is called from another fragment, even calling it from my main activity ends in the same result. Think I may just delete my class and start again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved it, if you have an RecyclerView with a height of match_parent, this steals the focus from the edittext and doesn't allow it to be set. Changing the height to wrap_content solved the issue.